# How to open a .xlsx file exported from OracleDB?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

A team member has several reports he extracts in a daily manner from different reports on Oracle and dump them into their respective single sheet `.xlsx` file so he can open them with Excel latter and do some scrubbing. I want to automate the whole task with Pandas, but I haven't been able to open the downloaded file with any of the libraries available from Python.

When I try to open the file with Pandas, XLRD throws the following error:

```py
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0414e67ce665> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel("small_data_samples/ruben/Actividades-Conectar Arreglos Pymes_30_07_19.xlsx")

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/datas--Z8piCS3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    143         if 'content.xml' in component_names:
    144             raise XLRDError('Openoffice.org ODS file; not supported')
--> 145         raise XLRDError('ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook')
    146 
    147     from . import book

XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook
```

I tried also using Openpyxl, with no better luck:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a458f5d28de0> in <module>
----> 1 book = openpyxl.load_workbook("small_data_samples/ruben/Actividades-Conectar Arreglos Pymes_30_07_19.xlsx")

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/datas--Z8piCS3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, guess_types, keep_links)
    221             ws._rels = rels
    222             ws_parser = WorkSheetParser(ws, fh, shared_strings)
--> 223             ws_parser.parse()
    224 
    225             if rels:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/datas--Z8piCS3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py in parse(self)
    128             tag_name = element.tag
    129             if tag_name in dispatcher:
--> 130                 dispatcher[tag_name](element)
    131                 element.clear()
    132             elif tag_name in properties:

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/datas--Z8piCS3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py in parse_row(self, row)
    290 
    291         for cell in safe_iterator(row, self.CELL_TAG):
--> 292             self.parse_cell(cell)
    293 
    294 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/datas--Z8piCS3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py in parse_cell(self, element)
    209         if style_id is not None:
    210             style_id = int(style_id)
--> 211             style_array = self.styles[style_id]
    212 
    213         if coordinate:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried using the ZipFile library to open the file and extract the .xml content I needed, in there I found this:

```py
[Content_Types].xml
_rels/
_rels/.rels
_rels/workbook.xml.rels
sheet1.xml
styles.xml
workbook.xml
```

I was able to identify than `sheet1.xml` was the content I was looking for, but that's a really heavy and convoluted `.xml`, and I want to avoid going that way unless there is no better approach.

Up to now I haven't been able to open the file with Python, but I'm able to open the file with Excel and LibreOffice in Windows and Linux. If I do that and save the file again, then I'm able to open it up with Pandas, directly with XLRD and also with Openpyxl.

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if you modified `openpyxl` at "openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py" to catch the exception and ignore it.  `openpyxl` is setting the style array for that cell.  Unfortunately, the style array would contain formatting information and formatting information is the only way to tell that you have a date in excel.  But perhaps this is a corner case where the formatting isn't needed.  Perhaps it doesn't apply to all the cells.  Or perhaps `openpyxl` is completely choking on an irregularity in "styles.xml".

Comment: XLRD is for old-style binary `*.xls` format; openpyxl is the right choice for the xlsx files. Judging from [this openpyxl bug report](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/856/load_workbook-throws-index-error), there's a chance the files you have are "broken" (not conforming to the OOXML standard), but it's hard to see without having access to them. If they are, fixing the process that generates them or hacking your copy of openpyxl seem like your two best bets.